# No module named django but it is installed

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pythonpath

I have two versions of python 2.7 and 3.4 and installed django through pip. it shows in ubuntu terminal:

```
$ pip freeze
Django==1.6.11
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb  3 2016, 02:50:32) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

Any idea??

Comment: Show output of `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: @soon >>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>>

Answer (score 65):

Probably, `pip` installs packages into `dist-packages` directory, which is not included into `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. You have a couple of solutions:

1. Create and configure [`virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for your project, before using `pip`. This is the most Pythonic way
2. Try to install `Django` using [built-in pip module](https://docs.python.org/2/installing/):

   ```
   python -m pip install django
   ```

   This command should install packages into `site-packages` directory.
3. You may also add `dist-packages` to your `PYTHONPATH`. This question should help you: [How to globally modify the default PYTHONPATH (sys.path)?](https://superuser.com/questions/247620/how-to-globally-modify-the-default-pythonpath-sys-path)

Comment: This solved my problem with "No Module named django.core". Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! #1 didn't work (hence why I came to this question) and #2 fixed it.

Comment: Thank you both for asking and answering the question!! I was going crazy with this same issue.

Answer (score 10):

This error shows that Django is not installed. Installing Django should solve the problem.

In my case, Django was there in my virtualenv but while using gunicorn I was getting this error then later I realized gunicorn was dealing with my globally install python environment not my virtual environment installing Django on my global python env simply solved my issue.

```
pip install django
```

Answer (score 8):

I got this error when using

```
python manage.py runserver #python version 3 was being used
```

Solved the problem by using:

```
python2 manage.py runserver #python version 2
```

Comment: Note, that starting with django 2.0 you cannot use Python2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django

Answer (score 8):

I had the similar error for other modules which are already installed, executing same command as superuser:

`sudo pip3 install -r  requirements.txt`

solved my issue.

Comment: This solved it for me.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to close the other active virtual environment in your machine if you're using virtualenv, and make sure django installed. Go to python3 interpreter and run this:

```
>>>from django import get_version
>>>get_version()
```

make sure it show you this '2.1.4'

Answer (score 3):

For Mac users; If you've previously downloaded and installed python3, just running `python` via the terminal shell defaults to using the pre-installed python v2, which will not recognise your installation of django (unless you install it via the python2 module) and you'll probably get an error when you check the version:

```
$ python

>>> from django import get_version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

Try starting python using:

```
$ python3
```

Then try:

```
>>> from django import get_version
>>> get_version()
```

You should get the output:

```
'2.0.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

`python3 manage.py migrate` solved my problem
I was getting this error while running:
`python manage.py migrate`
I changed to `python3 ...`

Comment: I too was using python2 when I thought I was using 3.  `python3 -m pip install django` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had given the dependency in `requirements.txt` as `Django==2.0.7`. So after activating the virtual environment, if you are receiving the message, try installing the requirements:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the Django.

I was getting the same issue because I had an older version of Django installed. I installed the latest version of Django instead and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. i was using python 3.7 and installed django 2.2. So i degraded my python to 3.6 and installed django 2.2, and without having a virtualenv.

Comment: it is something to do with version... but still you dont have to downgrade it. i am running python3.7 with django 2.2.2 and inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue today. doing  `pip3 install django` or `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` solved it.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you created your app properly and define it in `settings.py` file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

 ....

'app_name.apps.AppNameConfig',
]
```

sometimes, not defining your app name in `settings.py` or unwanted typo causes the same type of error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with you when try to setup Apache work with Django.
Issue solve after add Pythonpath to Apache2.conf as bellow:

```
WSGIPythonPath/opt/djangoprojects/myproject:opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

I installed Python3 before.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows you didn't install Django. Installing Django should solve the problem.

Once you do, you can just check the path of "django" using:

```
>>> sys.path
```

Answer (score 0):

For MacOs,I was getting the same issue while using import django.I deactivated conda and again activated django virtual environment by conda.Then made sure the python version is correct,in my case it was python 3.8.5.Then navigate to the project's directory and run the required python script.
My Django version is 3.1.5

Answer (score 0):

### Unistall/Install

Confirm that you're running from virtualenv of you have installed the app to venv.

If you made sure that it has been installed and still shows mdule not found, uninstall and install again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `env` not running after you shut down your computer. Just need to `pipenv shell` to launch again the virtual environment.

Then u can see this one the terminal

```
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /Users/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/little-lemon-O3-M0emD/bin/activate
```

and, type `python3 manage.py runserver` to start your django server and work normally.