# Django ModuleNotFoundError "django" module

Tags: python, django

I just started back in Django (so I am back from scratch) and now I'm trying the tutorials from Django for now and I am getting moduleError thingy.

[image]

[image]

For some reason, I cannot import anything thru urls.py and I haven't found a way to resolve it.

Is it in the local folder I created in project? or is there something that needs to be added to PATH (which I believe I already did)?

Also if I check the terminal logs, it shows this relating to "django":

[image]

Any suggestions how to make them work?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184458/no-module-named-django-but-it-is-installed

Comment: I already tried matching the python version with a compatible django version. but the same error still occurs. I am quite lost as I did not encounter this the last time I remember I used the tool. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you most create a virtual enviroment to install the packages related to this project:

```
pip install virtualenv 
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

know you can install django:

```
pip install django
```

and run your project.